# Put website into a folder, don't show folder on URL, and still have access to other folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I'm trying to host my website into a folder on the FTP, for example, /site. But on the URL i want to remove this folder, so it will be www.mysite.com.br instead of www.mysite.com.br/site.

I've already achieved it using this rewrite script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/$1 [L]
```

But know when i try to access other files into other folders withing the server, i get a "This webpage has a redirect loop", for example, www.mysite.com.br/downloads/myfile.zip.

Does anyone have any idea how to make Rewrite only don't consider existing files within other folders than /site?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#Alias) to do this:

```
Alias / /path/to/site
```